# Why are multiple tables being created when I try to create a dataTable from XML?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I am attempting to create a `DataTable` from an XML file. Here is my code:

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable sqlTable = new DataTable("SqlTable");
        sqlTable.Columns.Add("Team");
        ds.Tables.Add(sqlTable); 
        if (File.Exists(pathToXmlFile))
        {
            //sqlTable.Tables[0].TableName = "ServerXML";
            //sqlTable.ReadXmlSchema(pathToXmlFile);
            ds.ReadXml(pathToXmlFile);
            foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);

                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(row[column].ToString());
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            File.AppendAllText(pathToLogFile, Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + ": ServerXml.xml could not be found. A database table could not be created.");
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is, that the `ds.ReadXml(pathToXmlFile)` line is making multiple tables out of the XML. Here is the format of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items found="132" limit="1000">
    <sampleField>
        <att1>18
        </att1>
        <att2>4343
        </att2>
        <att3>94007961
        </att3>
        <att4>Test
        </att4>
        <att5>Example
        </att5>
    </sampleField>

    <sampleField>
        <att1>40
        </att1>
        <att2>8945
        </att2>
        <att3>94089741
        </att3>
        <att4>Test2
        </att4>
        <att5>Example2
        </att5>
    </sampleField>
</items>
```

How can I achieve creating a single table, with the `<sampleField>` tags representing different entries?

Comment: Why aren't you using DataTable.ReadXml() instead of DataSet?

Comment: I tried that, but I got an error that said this: `DataTable does not support schema inference from Xml.`

Comment: Try loading your XML into an XmlDocument and traversing the nodes to create your table.

Comment: @sr28 Thanks for the advice. Do you know of somewhere that I can see an example implementation of this?

Comment: I wish people would answer the question In this case it is real simple.  You are getting two tables.  The 1st table contains the attributes : found and limit.  The 2nd table contains the rows sampleFields (2 rows)

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the answer. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can go about getting a single table with the `<sample>` tags representing the different entries, and the `<att1> - <att5>` tags representing the column names? Does this make sense?

Comment: It is table[1].  Table[0] has only the attributes.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks. I see what you mean. My end goal with this is to create a table in a SQL Server database from `ds.Table[1]`.

Comment: I would manually create the table in SQL using SQL Server Management studio (SSMS) and define the column in SSSMS which is only done once.  Then use a INSERT SQL statement in c# to save data in database.  It is pretty simple to enumerate through the datatabe and savve daTA.

Comment: @jdweng I will do that. Thanks. Your comment that says that `ds.Tables[1]` is where the rows are stored is the correct answer to my question. If you write an answer that says this, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

create an entity class sampleField

```
public class sampleField
{
 public string att1{get;set;}
 public string att2{get;set;}
 public string att3{get;set;}
 public string att4{get;set;}
 public string att5{get;set;}
}
```

Use this helper

```
public static sampleField  ObjectToXML(string XmlOfAnObject, Type ObjectType) {
  StringReader StrReader = new StringReader(XmlOfAnObject);
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(ObjectType);
  XmlTextReader XmlReader = new XmlTextReader(StrReader);
  try {
    sampleField AnObject = serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader);
    return AnObject;
  } catch (Exception exp) {
    //Handle Exception Code
  } finally {
    XmlReader.Close();
    StrReader.Close();
  }
}
```